# match a pattern and its following lines until blank line

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a file like this:

```
# a
some
lines

# b
some
more
lines

...
```

Say I want to match that `# b` paragraph:

```
# b
some
more
lines
```

I know that `grep "# b" filename` can match that line of pattern that I am interested in, but I don't know how to perform "match until blank line" action. Not sure if grep is better than sed or awk for this task. Help?

Comment: first, by showing your attempts :)

Comment: As you mentioned `awk`, which is subjectively the best for this problem, you should see this: [How to select lines between two patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns). Blank line in `awk` can be matched with: `/^$/` where `^` is the beginning and `$` the end of string.

Comment: @JamesBrown the accepted answer of that post is a really comprehensive one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [address ranges](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html) in sed:

```
sed -n '/^# b/,/^$/p'
```